# Google Play Services Leaderboard - score is only posted when leaderboard is opened

Tags: android, google-play-services, leaderboard

I have an Android game with Leaderboard implementation. My problem is that everything seems fine the user and his score only appears when he opens the leaderboard. 
In the Activity I call this in onCreate:

```
if (!isSignedIn()) {
        beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
    }
    if (getApiClient().isConnected()) {
        Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard), totalScoreLong);
    }
```

When opening the leaderboard:

```
if (!isSignedIn()) {
                beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
            } else {
                startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard)), 2);
            }
```

Also, when a user finishes a round in the game I try to send the updated score:

```
if (getApiClient().isConnected()) {
            Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard), totalLong);
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? I cannot see the user in the leadboard until he opens it.... Guess it should not work this way because I have seen other apps with 1000s of users and I don't think everybody views the leaderboards. I have many users on the app so this should not be the problem and I have also tested with 2 devices and the user was not visible.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try doing the same with GoogleApi instead of GoogleApiClient? In that way you would get rid of handeling the connection state where you might have some issues.

You can also use `submitScoreImmediate` method which will try to asynchronously load the score and return you the data as a result.

Example:

```
Games.getLeaderboardsClient(ctx, signIn)
    .submitScoreImmediate(id, score)
    .addOnSuccessListener(
      new OnSuccessListener<ScoreSubmissionData>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ScoreSubmissionData data) {
          ...
        }
      });
```